# Why is my GroupBy -> SelectMany routine working?

Tags: c#, reference

I wrote this myself 6+ months ago, and now I can't remember why it works...

I have the following piece of code:

```
var grouped = alleSkjema.GroupBy(q => q.OrgID);
var newGroupList = grouped.Where(q => q.Count() < 4).SelectMany(p => p).ToList();
newGroupList.ForEach(p => p.OrgID = u.tre.First().orgid);
```

Where `alleSkjema` is an `IEnumerable<T>` with some properties. `OrgID` is a Department ID of sorts and the `T` in this context is a Person.

What I'm doing in the above code is grouping everyone belonging to a department of less than 4 persons in their own group. This is for anonymity reasons and really not important for the solution.

What happens next is that with only the three lines above, `alleSkjema` is modified, and I can't figure out why. I guess mutability is biting me in the ass? I thought I needed to do what I'm doing in the last line to the `alleSkjema` collection also to get the intended result. Does the `newGroupList` somehow contain a reference to the `alleSkjema` collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The culprit is here: `p.OrgID = u.tre.First().orgid`

You aren't "duplicating" the objects, so the items contained in `alleSkjema` are a superset of the items cointained in `newGroupList`. To be clear, if `X` is contained in `alleSkjema` and `X` passes the test, then `X` is put in `newGroupList`. The same `X`, not a copy of `X`. This because your objects are reference types.

Comment: So I'm not mutating `alleSkjema`. I'm mutating it's contents?

Comment: @ChristianWattengård Yep, exactly as you said.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give myself a facepalm and be on my way then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `alleSkjema` variable is not modified at all. However, it seems to contain references and the instances those references point to *are* modified by your last line.